# Outputting Time - a DateTime entry

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

#### Related:

> This is a continuation from my earlier question, [Wrong Logic in If Statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236245/wrong-logic-in-if-statement)

```
$repeat_times = mysql_real_escape_string($repeat_times);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `code`,`datetime` FROM `fc` ORDER by datetime desc LIMIT 25") or die(mysql_error());

$output .="";
$seconds = time() - strtotime($fetch_array["datetime"]);

if($seconds < 60)
  $interval = "$seconds seconds";
else
 if($seconds < 3600)
     $interval = floor($seconds / 60) . " minutes";
else
    if($seconds < 86400)
         $interval = floor($seconds / 3600) . " hours";
    else
         $interval = floor($seconds / 86400) . " days";

while ($fetch_array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $fetch_array["code"] = htmlentities($fetch_array["code"]);
    $output .= "<li><a href=\"http://www.***.com/?code=" . htmlspecialchars(urlencode($fetch_array["code"])) . "\" target=\"_blank\">" . htmlspecialchars($fetch_array["code"]) . "</a> (" . $fetch_array["datetime"] . ") </li>";


}

$output .="";

return $output;
```

Okay, fixed last problem.  Now it's just outputtign the [DateTime] function when I want it to output :

```
LINK (5 Seconds Ago)
LINK (1 Minute Ago)
etc.
```

It's doing:
    janice (2009-08-05 14:02:01)

Please advise?

Comment: VERY bad style! Especially with several nested `if..else`, absolutely { *use brackets* }!

Answer (score 1):

You are performing your calculation outside the loop. Move it inside the loop, like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `code`,`datetime` FROM `fc` ORDER by datetime desc LIMIT 25") or die(mysql_error());
$output = "";

while ($fetch_array = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $code = htmlentities($fetch_array["code"]);

    $seconds = time() - strtotime($fetch_array["datetime"]);
    if($seconds < 60)
        $interval = "$seconds seconds";
    else if($seconds < 3600)
        $interval = floor($seconds / 60) . " minutes";
    else if($seconds < 86400)
        $interval = floor($seconds / 3600) . " hours";
    else
        $interval = floor($seconds / 86400) . " days";

    $output .= "<li><a href=\"http://www.***.com/?code=" . urlencode($code) . "\" target=\"_blank\">$code</a> ($interval) </li>";
}

return $output;
```